# How do we write a higher order function in this example?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm merely trying to pass in a lambda function which results in a string to generally populate a special kind of lookup list. I'm trying to rewrite some code using higher order functions. The problem is that the `Add` method does not like the `keySelector` function. Here is the code, how I get it to compile please:

```
public static KeyedLookupList<TSource> Slug<TSource>(this List<TSource> items, 
                                                     Func<TSource, string> keySelector)
{
    var keyedLookupList = new KeyedLookupList<TSource>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        keyedLookupList.Add(keySelector, item);
    }

    return keyedLookupList;
}
```

Here is the Add method:

```
public override void Add(string key, TValue value)
{
    base.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(key, value));
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<TSource, string>' to 'string'
```

**Resolved thanks to @peeyush singh:**

```
public static KeyedLookupList<TSource> Slug<TSource>(this List<TSource> items,
        Func<TSource, string> keySelector)
    {
        var keyedLookupList = new KeyedLookupList<TSource>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            keyedLookupList.Add(keySelector(item), item);
        }

        return keyedLookupList;
    }
```

Comment: `Add()` has `string` as first parameter, you are trying to give it `Func<TSource, string>`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your add method takes a string as the first parameter, you are sending it a func and thats what the compiler is complaining. Should you call to add not be like Add(keySelector(item), item)

Comment: What type of `TValue value` in `public override void Add(string key, TValue value)` method?

Comment: @guy That just moves the same error message further down the stack: public override void Add(Func<string> key, TValue value)
        {
            base.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(key, value));
        } - At some point, we need to evaluate the function and actually return a string. That seems to be the problem I'm having.

Comment: @CarneyCode well `KeyValuePairr<string, TValue>` also has `string` as first parameter (the key)... What are you actually trying to do? I don't think you want `Func` as key.

Comment: @Guy Even the following give a similar error: public void Add<TSource>(Func<TSource, string> key, TValue value)
        {
            base.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(key, value));
        }

Comment: @CarneyCode Please read my previous comment.

Comment: @CarneyCode Could you provide definition of KeyedLookupList please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the func you need to pass the evaluated func, so like

```
keyedLookupList.Add(keySelector(item), item);
```

Comment: Utterly correct! I wasn't performing the evaluation anywhere. Thanks :)